# Why does my vga cable keep causing tv monitor to flash?

Tags: laptop, tv, vga

I have a Dell laptop with Windows 7, and use a monster vga cable to connect to my tv so I can watch DVDs. However lately the tv has been pausing/flashing at regular intervals and it gets really annoying since it has been doing this about 50 times during a movie. I've tried messing with the screen resolution and adjusting projector to only display my tv monitor but nothing seems to help. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried with another video source or another cable to see what really causes the problem?

Comment: Any warranty on the cable?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your cable has a break in it, some TVs will hold the last frame displayed when the signal is lost and this could account for the pauses/flashes. Do you have an old monitor with vga input to test it on?